# Get data from JSON with Axios

Tags: json, axios

My localhost:8080/omdb displays this :

[image]

and I want to get Titles, Years and imdbIDs from it.

Here's my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-COMPATIBLE" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Web Project 2018</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="searchResult">
    <h2>List of movies</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Title</b></td>
            <td><b>Year</b></td>
            <td><b>imdbID</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr v-for="film in films">
            <td>{{ film.Title }}</td>
            <td>{{ film.Year }}</td>
            <td>{{ film.imdbID }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#searchResult',
        data: {
            films: [],
            errors: [],
        },
        created() {
                axios.get('http://localhost:8080/omdb')
                        .then(response => {
                            this.films = response.data;
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            this.errors.push(error);
                        });
        }
    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the view displays nothing but this :

[image]

Any ideas why I can't get the values please ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please try to JSON.parse(response.data) ? or just let me know what console.log(typeof response.data) outputs ?

Comment: this.films = JSON.parse(response.data); doesn't work either

Comment: do you get parsing error ? is it a valid json? what data type is returned from the response?

Comment: It's a JsonArray I believe.

Thing is, when I use this link : http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=37fb0bca&s=batman

And this.films = response.data.Search

It works fine.

Maybe because there's no key at the beggining ?

Comment: it's kind of hard to debug it without the server-side code. what does console.log(typeof response.data) outputs ?

Comment: ohhhh yeah that's correct...the key is the one that contains your array of objects

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined.

Comment: So on my screenshot in the original post, how do I get the Title, Year and imdbID keys, knowing that ?

Comment: ok I figured it out. just do the following this.films = response

Comment: response is the actual array of objects, not sure why there was this.films = response.data (what is data?)

Comment: Doesn't work either... Still not populating my table !

Comment: ok that's strange, I will have to see your server-side code in order to help you

Comment: If it can help, my array is obtained with this code : 
https://gyazo.com/c47b43ef895a7cd0e47fa7b66a8b0083
As you can see, it's the same file but I just get the value of the "Search" key

Comment: can you try to hard code the this.film object ? like so: this.films = [
{
Title: "Batman Begins",
Year: "2005",
imdbID: "tt0372784",
Type: "movie",
Poster: "https://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BYzc4ODgyZmYtMGFkZC00NGQyLWJiMDItMmFmNjJiZjcxYzVmXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDYyMDk5MTU@._V1_SX300.jpg"
}];

Comment: Still nothing, didn't think of it but that's strange

Comment: sorry please consider the following code instead: var Obj = {}; Obj.Search = []; Obj.Search.push(response.data); this.films = Obj;

Comment: Doesn't work. 
I tried something : now my localhost:8080/omdb display the EXACT same thing as the gyazo link (WITH the Search key). When I put the omdbapi link into the axios.get(), it works. But when i put http://localhost:8080/omdb, it does not. Maybe it just reach it ?

Comment: personally I would prepare it like so to the client instead of let the client to compute the data

Comment: that's really strange...

Comment: I get this when I open the browser's console : Failed to load http://localhost:8080/omdb: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access. That might be it.